# Randomize tests Android

Tags: user-interface, android-testing, android-espresso, random

I have an activity with spinners (3), an EditText (1), buttons (2). I would like to test whether the order of user interactions with these elements does not matter for the outcome (=display of some string in a TextView). For example it should not matter whether I first type something in the EditText and then select a spinner or whether I first do the spinner selection and then type something in the EditText, etc.

Due to the number of elements, there are many variations of how user interactions could happen. Is there a way to either:

1. generate automatically all possible combinations of user interactions/testing code

or

2. Test a single, but random user interaction
   ?

I am aware of The Monkey, but that seems to be for stress testing only!?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

```
generate automatically all possible combinations of user interactions/testing code
```

Sorry, but I don't see any rational way to test it in the other way than in `monkey`.

Please read more about this tool here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html
and Trust me, there's no reason to be afraid of this great tool.

Finally, `monkey` also gives you well-detiled logs, as you can see on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdDVHXo4obY